# How can I incorporate TypeScript within a Next.js project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

In the past I created a project using Webpack. Webpack autocompiled the TypeScript in my project to JS and outputed it into a bundle.js which I then imported. I now have a new project, written using Next.js and React. However I am struggling to move my previously written code over. I don't recall setting up Webpack with my new project, but Next.js appears to use Webpack when I run "npm run dev" because it prints `info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5` to the console after.

My new project uses TypeScript, React and Next.js, my old project used Webpack and Typescript. How can I bring over my old Typescript and have it work with my new project? All of the tutorials of using TypeScript with Next.js or React all include .tsx files and do not include custom TypeScript. My Typescript code is a Three.js application that grabs the canvas element and renders the scene, they're hidden away in their own `typescript/my_threejs.ts` files.

Comment: Next 11 uses webpack 5.  TSX is typed (typescript) jsx. You can place TS in TSX files. React renders JSX - you need to convert your code to use JSX.  You can also use TS files in react for ts without JSX i.e. types and functions. It might be easiest to use a threejs react library and port your code.

Comment: That sounds like a mission, can it not be as simple as editing my next.js webpack to find all of my TypeScript files, and output a bundle.js for which I can then import like in my previous project?

Comment: Next.js is a React framework. You'll need to adapt your current app to React, otherwise why move to Next.js at all? But maybe I'm missing something - do you have sample code that you're trying to migrate?

Comment: +1 to juilo's comment - I don't think it's that straight forward - I wouldn't port it to just have it in React unless there was a reason.  You will need to hook into React's lifecycle methods.  Since you're wanting Nextjs - you'll likely also need to hook into some of their methods as well depending on how you will be rendering the app.